# Pandas Pivot Table: Error when filtering by condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

I have a dataframe which I pivoted and trying to create a updated dataframe when the values meet certain condition. The problem, I have is the values in the columns are structured in two lines. The comparison needs to be done on line1 of the value. For example, if the col7 value is '100.2\n11', then I need to compare 100.2 against the condition and if it satisfies the condition, then the final dataframe should contain the full value('100.2\n11') of the data and not just 100.2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    'col2': ['test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test2', 'test2', 'test2',
             'test2', 'test3', 'test3', 'test3', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5',
             'test1', 'test1'],
    'col3': ['t1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1',
             't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1'],
    'col4': ['input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input4', 'input1', 'input2',
             'input3', 'input4', 'input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input5',
             'input2', 'input6', 'input1', 'input1'],
    'col5': ['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result1', 'result2',
             'result3', 'result4', 'result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4',
             'result2', 'result1', 'result2', 'result6'],
    'col6': [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 50, 20, 100, 10, 10],
    'col7': ['100.2\n11','101.2\n21','102.3\n34','101.4\n41','100.0\n10','103.0\n20.6','104.0\n31.2','105.0\n42','102.0\n10.2',
             '87.0\n15','107.0\n32.1','110.2\n61.2','120.0\n22.4','88.0\n90','106.2\n16.2','101.1\n10.1']})

df1=df.pivot_table(values = 'col7', index = ['col4', 'col5', 'col6'], columns = ['col2'], aggfunc = 'max')
df2 = df1[((df1.groupby(level='col4').rank(ascending=False) == 1.).any(axis=1)) & (df1 >= 105).any(axis=1)]

print(df2)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
  File "pandas\_libs\ops.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_compare
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

The final pivot table output after the condition is satisfied should be as follows:

```
col2                   test1          test2           test3         test4        test5
col4   col5    col6                                                
input1 result2 10    106.2\n16.2       NaN             NaN           NaN          NaN
input2 result2 20    101.2\n21      103.0\n20.6      87.0\n15      120.0\n22.4    NaN
input3 result3 30    102.3\n34      104.0\n31.2     107.0\n32.1      NaN          NaN
input4 result4 40    101.4\n41      105.0\n42           NaN          NaN          NaN
input5 result4 50       NaN            NaN          110.2\n61.2      NaN          NaN
```

Any guidance is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to create an auxiliary dataframe that contains only the first line values from `df1` and then apply it to the filter conditions.

```py
...
...
df1=df.pivot_table(values = 'col7', index = ['col4', 'col5', 'col6'], columns = ['col2'], aggfunc = 'max')

df_tmp = df1.applymap(lambda x: float(str(x).split('\n')[0]))

df2 = df1[
    ((df_tmp.groupby(level='col4').rank(ascending=False) == 1.).any(axis=1)) &
    (df_tmp >= 105).any(axis=1)
]

print(df2)
```

```py
col2                       test1        test2        test3        test4 test5
col4   col5    col6
input1 result2 10    106.2\n16.2          NaN          NaN          NaN   NaN
input2 result2 20      101.2\n21  103.0\n20.6     87.0\n15  120.0\n22.4   NaN
input3 result3 30      102.3\n34  104.0\n31.2  107.0\n32.1          NaN   NaN
input4 result4 40      101.4\n41    105.0\n42          NaN          NaN   NaN
input5 result4 50            NaN          NaN  110.2\n61.2          NaN   NaN
```